# Coca Cola on Pesach

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, hechsher-certification

Yabia Omer writes that Citric Acid isn't a issue on Pesach. Does that deem Coca Cola Kosher for Passover even without a hechsher as a Sefardi?

Answer (score 2):

*[this was written before the OP edited his question and made it sefardi-specific, I will leave it up for Ashkenazim interested in the question]*

For Ashkenazim, the problem with regular Coca Cola is not just the question of the citric acid but rather the high-fructose corn syrup. See [here](http://www.jewishjournal.com/passover/article/the_story_of_passover_coca_cola) for instance

> In its year-round formula, Coca-Cola uses high-fructose corn syrup for
>   sweetness. But for Ashkenazim — Jews of Eastern European descent —
>   corn and corn-based products are forbidden during Passover. To satisfy
>   the sweet tooth of Jews who strictly observe Passover, Coca-Cola
>   substituted cane sugar for corn syrup.

Or see [here](https://newrepublic.com/article/112747/112747) which focuses on the fact that some non-Jews prefer Pesach Coke

> During Passover, Jews are forbidden to eat a category of grains known
>   as kitniot, which includes corn. The Ashkenazi rabbis who came up with
>   this stricture many centuries ago probably didn't foresee how their
>   edict would collide with the invention of high fructose corn syrup
>   [...] the end result today is that there are all sorts of
>   HFCS-sweetened products that are kosher for most of the year but are
>   not kosher during Passover. In some cases, special Passover editions
>   of these products—sweetened with cane sugar, which is
>   Passover-sanctioned, instead of HFCS—appear on the market in the weeks
>   leading up to the holiday.

Comment: Also citric acid could very well be a problem as it is often derived from wheat

Comment: mbloch you haven't cited any support for "For Ashkenazim, the problem with regular Coca Cola is not the citric acid" which is the only part of this which remotely addresses the question.

Comment: Note even for Ashkenazim the corn syrup in the Coca Cola may be Batel if purchased before Pesach.

Comment: Is this a question for a Rav? It doesn't fit to this forum?

Comment: The Conservative Rabbis just declared that it's okay to eat corn on Pesach.

Answer (score 0):

According to Rav Yitzchak Abadi, coca cola is inherently kosher for Sephardim and Ashkenazim during Passover without a hecsher according to halakha.

His responses are as follows:

> Questioner:   Is it permitted to drink plain coca cola on Pesach?
>
> Rabbi Abadi: Yes

Source: http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=56956&highlight=coca%20cola

> Questioner: What's going on here? (copied from a Jerusalem Post
>   article)
>
> "Kosher for Passover Coca-Cola has been barred from California.
>
> California's new state laws on toxic chemicals are keeping kosher for
>   Passover Coke out of the state, a company spokesman told the San
>   Gabriel Valley Tribune. Related:
>
> Coke was required to change the way it manufactures caramel due to the
>   high levels of the chemical 4-methylimidazole, or 4-MEI, which
>   California has listed as a carcinogen under its new guidelines. The
>   manufacturing changes in California affected the kosher for Passover
>   status of the cola, according to reports.
>
> The company expects to offer the Kosher for Passover variety of coca
>   cola in California by 2013, the newspaper reported citing the company
>   spokesman.
>
> The Passover version of Coke uses sugar in place of corn syrup, which
>   is not kosher for Passover for Ashkenazi Jews. Some kosher stores in
>   California carried limited amounts of kosher for Passover Coke, which
>   bears a yellow cap, imported from other states. "
>
> Thanks again and moed tov.
>
> Michael
>
> Rabbi Abadi:  It would be Halachically permitted for Ashkenazim, but
>   they choose too be Machmir

Source: http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=51992&highlight=coca%20cola

> Questioner: ...why is it that they produce a special Peasach Coke (it
>   tastes awful :) if the regular one is okay? Thanks for all you help.
>
> Rabbi Badi: It is a business decision

Source: http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=51660&highlight=coca%20cola

Comment: Worth noting that R Abadi is known for being incredibly lenient about supervision requirements in general, so this response isn't necessarily indicative of how most rabbis would rule.